# Is there a word that includes/encompasses both ‘mouse button’ and ‘keyboard key’?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, computing

Is there a word that both describes keys on a keyboard as well as mouse buttons? They are quite similar, as in you press down on them, yet it is still called *press a key* and *click a mouse button.*

Three words I thought of are

- *switch*
- *button*
- *key*

but these all are a bit generic and don’t show that both the keyboard and the mouse are meant.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52473/discussion-on-question-by-kim366-is-there-a-word-that-includes-encompasses-both).

Comment: It depends on what you're writing. If it's user documentation you need to be as clear as possible, even at the expense of brevity. After all there's a lot of truth behind the old story of the user looking for the 'any' key in response to the command 'press any key to continue'! If you're writing for a technical audience (perhaps describing the lower level functioning of a piece of software) you could refer to _interrupt_ or _user input_.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to tell if other things might fit with your name. Does a stylus count? A touch screen? A 3D motion sensor (Kinect)? A breath sensor? Does there have to be feedback from the device? A haptic glove?

Comment: No, this specifically applies to anything that makes a tactile sound, like a keyboard key, mouse button or joystick button

Comment: Please [edit] this to add what research you've done.

Answer (score 3):

Your could go with [Haptic Interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology)

> Haptic or kinesthetic communication recreates the sense of touch by applying forces, vibrations, or motions to the user.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology) This mechanical stimulation can be used to assist in the creation of virtual objects in a computer simulation, to control such virtual objects, and to enhance the remote control of machines and devices (telerobotics). **Haptic devices may incorporate tactile sensors that measure forces exerted by the user on the interface**.

Although we associate *haptics* with devices that "talk back" such as the rumble of a gaming console controller, the category also includes devices which measure the human touch in order to interface with a machine. Keyboard, mouse, touch screen...

Comment: I disagree. 'haptic' implies that there is something that 'talks back' and clicks of a mouse or keyboard are not that.

Comment: @Mitch I believe there is _some_ feedback from a mouse or keyboard, which is what distinguishes them from, say, a touchscreen.

Answer (score -5):

I'd bend things a bit and go for...

> [**keyclicks**](http://www.sustworks.com/keyclick_pref/index.html)

...which is "officially" defined as *the sound produced by a keypress*. But given the close association between ***mouse*** and ***click***, it's an obvious extension for OP's *keypresses and mouse clicks* context.

Comment: This is a really weird suggestion